How can I use a form to write data into two datasource?
I have two tables: one is a summary table containing two fields, PartID and Qty, and the other is a detail table containing records of each purchase, with fields for the purchase date, PartID, and Qty. My requirement is to have a form or something similar where, when a new purchase record is added, a new record is created in the detail table. At the same time, a corresponding record is also added to the summary table. the expected result should looks like this.
(https://i.sstatic.net/gwKbWK1I.png)
What formula should I enter on the button
